# Is it valid that $\int_0^b f(x) \; dx = \lim_{h \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{b}{h}} hf(kh)$?

Tags: integration, limits, summation

I've recently stumbled upon an equation:
$$\int_0^b f(x) \; dx = \lim_{h \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{\frac{b}{h}} hf(kh).$$

What I don't understand about this equation is the fact that the upper limit of the sum is $\frac{b}{h}$, and since $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h}$ is undefined, the upper limit of the sum also has to be undefined. But when I tried to test this equation on Desmos, it worked just fine. The question is, is this equation even valid, considering the fact that the upper limit of the sum is undefined?

Comment: The upper limit is infinity

Comment: So does that mean that $lim_{h \to 0} \frac{b}{h} = \infty$?, but that would contradict the fact that the limit as x approaches 0 of any number divided by x is always undefined (do not exist).

Comment: It does not matter in this case. You can't take separately the limits. I'll give a full answer below.

Comment: You have to let $h \to 0^+$ and not just $h \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have a rectangle, of length $b$ and width $w$. The area of the rectangle is $bw$. Now let's split this rectangle in $N$ pieces along $b$, each with width $b/N$. The area of each of these small rectangles is $bw/N$. Then the area of the original rectangle is $$\sum_{k=1}^N\frac{bw}N=bw$$
But you can split the rectangle in as many pieces as you want. The formula is valid in the limit $N\to\infty$ as well. In the original problem they use the width of the small rectangle as $h$, so $Nh=b$. You can then write $$N=\frac bh$$ and the area is $$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac bh}hw=bw$$
The last step is to allow the width of the small rectangles to vary as a function of position $w(x)=w(kh)=f(kh)$.